# Apache Tomcat not accessible from outside

Tags: tomcat, port

We have Tomcat 6 installed and running on an external facing server. It is set to listen to port 8082. I was able to see the default welcome page through localhost:8082. In addition, our network guy has already granted access for 8082 communications. However, this server is still not accessible from outside(with http://ip:8082).

Can someone please share some wisdom?

Thanks,

Comment: Ask your network guy to verify that the port is indeed open to the outside.

Comment: You may want to ask this on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with something simple.  Try telnetting to port 8082 on that IP address.  If your Tomcat instance is up and running and listening on port 8082 but you can't telnet to it, then it's not getting through your firewall (regardless of what your network guy says).

Comment: Actually, telnet is disabled and the firewall has been turned of on the server side.

Comment: When you telnet to port 8082, you're just opening up a TCP socket on that port.  You're not trying to establish a typical telnet session.  It will let you quickly determine if the port is available or if it's being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Tomcat Connector port to **8080** or even **80** if possible.
According to IANA
http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers
HTTP alternative port is **8008**, which I haven't tried before.

I would imagine if you are in a big corporation network, they may have a policy disabling outbound traffic to nonstandard ports.  Only the network administrator knows best what is allowed and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

add port 8082 to TCP Rules in Security Groups .