# Spring Boot and tomcat access from outside

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, server

For a few days I've been trying to solve this problem by searching on stackoverflow and other sites but I can't find it.

I currently have a spring boot application converted to jar running on a server. This application is accessible via a browser using the localhost on port 8080 by using tomcat which was directly integrated to my spring boot application.

The problem is the following:

We will tell here that the ip address of my server is 123.45.69.894

If I type :

```
localhost:8080/mypath
```

or if I type :

```
123.45.69.894:8080/mypath
```

in the browser of the server. I have this that appears in the console when I make the request :

```
2022-05-21 08:23:26.094  INFO 7536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-21 08:23:26.094  INFO 7536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-21 08:23:26.109  INFO 7536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 15 ms
```

and everything works well.

But if I type,

```
123.45.69.894:8080/mypath
```

in the browser of another computer it doesn't work anymore and I have a connection time out error and nothing appears in the console.

I have already checked if the firewall doesn't blocked the port 8080. But the problem is not there.

I have also on the port 80 an IIS web site, the problem can come from there ?

I have already looked at these articles for example but that doesn't work for me :

[how to deploy Spring boot application in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990154/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-application-in-iis)

[Apache Tomcat not accessible from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135145/apache-tomcat-not-accessible-from-outside)

Does anyone know where the problem might come from and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the remote machine, try pinging your IP address. If it times out there is definitely a firewall issue between the machines.
If ping works, try telnet IP port. If on Windows you may need to enable telnet from setup/applications. If telnet connects, the
there will be no action until you hit cntrl square bracket. If that works then everything should work ok.

Comment: After a recheck, contrary to what my network consultant told me, it was the firewall that was blocking the connections. Thank you for your reply